# Is there a way to compare multiple tuples within a tuple with user input

Tags: python

I have tuples within a tuple that I want to compare with user input. So far this is what I've tried

```
grade_data = (("Samira", "Chemistry", "A"), ("Carly", "Chemistry", "B"), ("Tyler", "Chemistry", "F"))

student = input("Which student would you like to view")

for i in grade_data:
    if student == i[0]:
        print("student found")
    else:
        print("Couldn't find try again")
```

However, it only shows the error message when I type in a correct student. I presume it's because I'm doing it within the loop which goes through the list until it finds the name so the output for Carly shows as:

```
Couldn't find try again
student found
Couldn't find try again
```

I want it to run through the list before it prints so I don't get multiple lines.

I've also tried just defining the list I want to iterate beforehand, for example:

```
for student in data:
    student = student[0]

stu_name = input("Which student would you like to view")

if stu_name == student:
    print("student found)
else:
    print("try again")
```

This has the same output as the first sequence of code.

Is there any other possible method that would go through the list and print "Try again" if it wasn't found in the list at all. If it is found in the list then it would just continue which out print "Couldn't find" for each line it doesn't find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the First case, remove the else part and add break statement in the if part.

```
grade_data = (("Samira", "Chemistry", "A"), ("Carly", "Chemistry", "B"), ("Tyler", "Chemistry", "F"))
student = input("Which student would you like to view? ")
for data in grade_data:
    if student == data[0]:
        print("student found: ", data[0], " Subject: ", data[1], " Grade:", data[2])
        break
```

Output:

```
Which student would you like to view? Carly
student found:  Carly  Subject:  Chemistry  Grade: B
```

Comment: I just made an edit to the post for clarification but I wanted to keep an error message when it wasn't found. If it was found I wouldn't be printing anything I would just simply move to the next sequence in my program.